# How to add a circular progressbar in my alertdialog?

Tags: android

I am displaying an `AlertDialog` from a Service. The problem is, I want to add a `ProgressBar`(circular) in my `AlertDialog`. How do I do this? I tried Replacing `AlertDialog` with `ProgressDialog`, but It would force close, I know this is not the right way anyways.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("APP IS OBSOLETE")
                    .setMessage("To continue, please wait for the updates to download.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("no, thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alert.show();
```

**PS: I want to do this within the service, without using any additional layouts.**

Comment: A Service should never display a dialog. I'm surprised it even worked for you. The UI will no be themed properly anyways. Instead, I recommend you show a notification, which may launch a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: @BladeCoder no wonder you would say that. the way you look. I can tell you are smart :)

Answer (score 2):

You should still use an `AlertDialog` but change the `View` that it shows.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView(android.view.View)

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(R.layout.my_progress_view)
        ...
```

Use this method on the builder: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(int)

`R.layout.my_progress_view` is an XML file that contains your `ProgressBar` (you create it the same way you create a layout for an Activity)

Comment: There is a challenge. I want to do this via a single service only, without additional design layouts

Comment: then create the View programmatically and use: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)

I've answered your question - your comment is a new question

Answer (score -1):

You should  use dialog.getContext() instead of context

```
`ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(dialog.getContext());
                     progressDialog.setMessage("Executing action...");
                     progressDialog.show(); `
```